# html5 video element, start and end times

Tags: html

I have an html5 video element.

```
 <video id="video" loop="loop">
   <source src="src.mov">
</video>
```

I want it to start at a certain time in the video (lets say... 10 seconds) and end at a certain time (27 seconds)

I know that you can do this in JavaScript, however I want to do this in html.  Is there a start / end time tag for the video element?

Comment: that's nice for JavaScript, but is it possible in HTML?

Comment: That method of specifying a playback range does not require JavaScript. Try disabling JavaScript in your browser and then load [this page](http://www.annodex.net/~silvia/itext/mediafrag.html). Notice that the video jumps to 20 seconds upon load. (Other functionality on that page *does* require JavaScript. For example, the "jump" button won't work without it.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can [specify a playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery#Specifying_playback_range) by appending the start and end times to the source URL.

The times should be in the format:

```
#t=[starttime][,endtime]
```

From MDN:

> The playback range portion of the media element URI specification was added to Gecko 9.0 (Firefox 9.0 / Thunderbird 9.0 / SeaMonkey 2.6).

Here's an example to play a video, starting from second 2 and ending at second 3:

```html
<video controls autoplay> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm#t=2,3 type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv#t=2,3 type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4#t=2,3 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp#t=2,3 type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

References:

[Temporal Dimension of Media Fragments URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#naming-time)
[Record of Mozilla integration (bug 648595)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648595)
Sample videos are from [techslides.com](http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5/)

Comment: Thanks!  This works great!  But one problem I have is, the video I have is looping, and when the video loops it starts back at the beginning.  Do you know of a way I can get it to start at the place specified?  Thanks Again!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a way to loop a fragment without JavaScript. However, I did find some [discussion](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/r8wmA7YRNZctPIrT4DzY) on the [difficulties](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=24910).

Comment: Not working here. Even i'have added #start,end doesn't shows working

Comment: @FernandoTorres You might want to post a new question to show your code and what's going wrong. Feel free to reference this one, if it's helpful.