# js video handling load at any second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am new to html5 and js

i have this html for testing

```
<video width="320" height="240">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtTC0.jpg)

i just want to load this video only from second (00:20) to second (00:30) for example

can i even do this with js?

*note: it dosen't matter to use pure js or jquery both cases are fine to me*

i searched but all i found is to seek the video and that was helpful
it is my first time working with video tab

**EDIT**
my job is more complicated i want to buffer some parts and ignore others
ya i can use start and endtime but that will only work for just one part

thanks BTW

Comment: tried googling for "html5 video start time end time"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665280/html5-video-element-start-and-end-times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 video element, start and end times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665280/html5-video-element-start-and-end-times)

Comment: see the edit please!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `#t=startTime,endTime` directly to your source's `src` attribute.

Try replacing :

```
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

By :

```
<source src="movie.mp4#t=20,30" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: yeah it worked, thanks. but my task is more complicated. i want to load parts and ignore other parts.

Comment: can i make something like `src = "movie.mp4#t=20,30,40,50"`

Comment: Yes you need to manipulate the video in javascript for that, you can take a look here, they listed the properties, events and methods you can use : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Comment: Do a `setInterval` to check current video time on `myPlayer.currentTime` and jump with it `myPlayer.currentTime(seconds)` depending on the time.

Comment: that's not what i want i can draw an illustration for my idea, wait a sec

Comment: \----------------|||||||||||||||||-------||----------------||||---------------------/

Comment: \ > that's a start , / > that's the end , ----------------- > that's the loaded .. ||||| > that's the ignored .. and say i have the seek cursor at the beginning

Comment: i don't need to move the cursor i just want these ----- parts to be buffered that's all

Comment: By doing a play/pause somewhere, you'll do start a preload at the position, I don't think you can do multi preloading in different positions at the same time.