# how to play a video from a specific startTime to a specific endTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

```
<video id='vsingle' src='test.mp4' poster='poster.jpg' controls></video>

<p class='story' data-start=5>lorem ipsum</p>
<p class='story' data-start=10>dolor sit</p>

var vid = document.getElementById("vsingle");

$('.story').on('click', function(){
  let x = $(this).attr('data-start');
  vid.currentTime=x;
  vid.play();
});
```

the above works fine - i.e. video starts from `x`
now I need to add `endTime` - something like this:

```
<p class='story' data-start=5 data-end=10>lorem ipsum</p>

$('.story').on('click', function(){
  let x = $(this).attr('data-start');
  let y = $(this).attr('data-end');
  vid.currentTime=x;
  vid.endTime = y;
  vid.play();  // from `x` to `y`
});
```

how to set the `endTime` and play the video from `x` to `y` ?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26665761/965852

Comment: @jonas - the snippet example on your link - doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

[Start HTML5 video at a particular position when loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981427/start-html5-video-at-a-particular-position-when-loading)

You can check this post, i am adding an example below:

```html
<video id='vsingle' src='https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-girl-crying-and-screaming-heartbroken-42253-large.mp4' poster='poster.jpg' controls></video>

<p class='story' data-start=5>lorem ipsum</p>
<p class='story' data-start=10>dolor sit</p>
```

```js
const vid = document.querySelector("#vsingle");

$('.story').on('click', function(){
  let x = $(this).attr('data-start');
  let y = $(this).attr('data-start');

  vid.currentTime=x;
  vid.play();

  video.addEventListener("progress", function(){
  if(video.currentTime >= y){
    video.pause();  
  }
}, false);
});
```

**!Alternate!**: Also You can add the url parameter:

```js
const vid = document.querySelector("#vsingle");
const url = vid.getAttribute('src')

$('.story').on('click', function(){
  let x = $(this).attr('data-start');
  let y = $(this).attr('data-end');

  vid.setAttribute('src', `${url}#t=${x},${y}`);
  vid.play();
});
```

Comment: hmm... interesting, thanks a lot, I will try